# Is python sort() broken? I don't get the output of max() on this list

Tags: python, sorting, key

I've been doing a course in Python, and got to the exercise where I have this code

```
words = ['pear', 'cabbage', 'apple', 'bananas']
words.sort(key=lambda s: s[-1])  # Alternatively, key=operator.itemgetter(-1)
words  # => ['cabbage', 'apple', 'pear', 'bananas'] ... Why 'cabbage' > 'apple'?
max(words, key=len)  # 'cabbage' ... Why not 'bananas'?
```

Can anyone explain, why does sorting orders the list in that way?

And why finding an item with max length returns wrong item? It is not the expected result at all.

Comment: For the sorting part: it's sorting the words by the last characters hence it is well sorted according to the specified policy

Comment: Why do you think `cabbage` is the "wrong item"? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the last character as sort criterion. Sorting is stable. Therefore, for this list:

```
words = ['pear', 'cabbage', 'apple', 'bananas']
```

`cabbage` and `apple` compare equal for the last letter and stay in the order they are in the original list.

For the same reason `max` gives you `cabbage`. Both have the same length:

```
>>> len('cabbage') == len('bananas')
True
```

and `cabbage` is before `bananas` in the original list.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) explain this well:

> The `sort()` method is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example, sort by department, then by salary grade).

Answer (score 2):

Your code `words.sort(key=lambda s:s[-1])` sorts the words by the last character of each of the words and if there are multiple possibilities it maintains the order in the original list.

If you need a regular alphabetical sort, then you need to use `words.sort()` and the result would be

```
>>> words.sort()
>>> words
['apple', 'bananas', 'cabbage', 'pear']
```

If you sort words by `key=len` then the list contains `[ ... , 'cabbage', 'bananas']`. `max()` finds the first value of the list of possible values and hence its result is `cabbage` as it appears before `bananas`

Comment: Thank you, and what about max()?

Comment: If you sort words by `key=len` then the list contains `['cabbage', 'bananas']`. `max()` finds the first value of the list of possible values and hence its result is `cabbage`

Answer (score 2):

Your Code is sorting according  to last index try this

```
words.sort(key=lambda s: s[0])
```

"bananas"and "cabbage" have same length. It search which one is first in list then print this first occurrence

Comment: Thank you, and what about the result of max()?